# Overlapping flex boxes or a different approach?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, margin

I'm looking for advice on how to approach the layout as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B88ht.jpg).

I'm not sure if flex alone can handle the overlapping green dotted boxes (using a transform?) or if the blocks should be flex boxes and the green dotted overlapping boxes should just be relatively positioned divs? The mobile version is fairly straight-forward as there's no overlapping involved but I'm unsure how to 'slice' the design up so the CSS can handle both situations.

Below is an initial attempt using `transform: scale`.

```css
.flex-box-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-box-row-box {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.flex-box-dots {
  max-height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  transform: scale(1.5, 1);
}

.flex-box-dots::after {
  content: "..................";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box-row">
  <div class="flex-box-row-box">
    BLOCK 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-box-dots"></div>
  <div class="flex-box-row-box">
    BLOCK 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-box-dots"></div>
  <div class="flex-box-row-box">
    BLOCK 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I've updated my post with my initial attempt, I'm still unsure if this is the best approach as using transform scale will also stretch the connecting dots.

Comment: You can also use something like `margin: 0 -20px;` to make the elements stretch beyond their normal boundaries, instead of the scale transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the overlapping effect by using negative margin! Here's an example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}

.green {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px dotted green;
  margin: 0 -30px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .green {
    width: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that seems a lot more straight forward than I was making it. Thank you (and to CBroe for the same answer).